# Obtaining the terms of a summation alongside the result

Tags: replacement, hold, term-rewriting, self-study

I have a `Sum` expression:

```
s := Sum[2x,{x,0,3}]
```

*As an exercise to explore the rewriting capabilities of the Wolfram Language, I would like to collect the result,* and *the different terms of the summation without changing the definition of the expression*. Something like that:

> ```
> {12,{0,2,4,6}}
> ```

The exact output format is not critical, as long as I have both the result, and the individual terms of the summation. After a fair amount of time, I end up with a solution I post as an [answer below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211067/68791). But it seems quite convoluted to me. Would you find a simpler solution to achieve my goal?

Comment: If I may, this smacks of [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me, especially the “without changing the definition of s” requirement. *Why* do you want to do this? Perhaps reformulating the problem in whose context this came up might sidestep this issue entirely.

Comment: @MarcoB As you know it now, I'm in the process of learning the Wolfram Language. This is a self-assigned exercise to explore with the expression rewriting capabilities of Mathematica. As mentioned in the question, I tried a couple of things before reaching a "working" solution. So I would have been curious to see how the community would solve such a problem _without_ [changing the rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kobayashi_Maru#Impact)

Comment: I rewrote the terms of the question to make it clear it was a self-assigned challenge. I also add the [tag:self-study] tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you considered [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html)?

```
s := Sum[2 x, {x, 0, 3}]

{s, Block[{Sum = Table}, s]}
```

> ```
> {12, {0, 2, 4, 6}}
> ```

Comment: Arghhh! So ... simple! I've already saw `Block`, but I didn't realize function names were symbols that could be rebound to something else. Mathematica is amazing!

Answer (score 3):

If evaluation of the term is okay, then you can use [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html)

```
s := Sum[2 x, {x, 0, 3}]
With[{seq = Trace@s}, {seq[[-1]], Cases[seq, x : {__} :> x[[-1]]]}] // ReleaseHold
```

> {12, {0, 2, 4, 6}}

Answer (score 3):

I would do it this way:

```
t = Table[2 x, {x, 0, 3}];
{Total[t], t}

{12, {0, 2, 4, 6}}
```

But if you really want to keep s fixed, you could do:

```
Trace[s][[All, -1]]
```

which gives you the terms you are looking for, though with the "12" repeated a couple of times.

Comment: Thanks, @Bill. But, as stated in the question, _"I don't want to change the definition of the summation `s`."_ Actually, this was a self-assigned exercise to learn about the Wolfram Language rewriting capabilities. I posted the question late in the evening, and I only realized this morning my intents were not clear. I rewrote the question to make that explicit. Sorry for having wasted your time.

BTW, thank you too for having mentioned `Trace`, a new tool in my toolbox ;)

Comment: Trace gives you (more or less) what you asked for. My first comment was meant to suggest that using := and Sum that way is probably not the best approach since it locks you into some odd constructs later on. But I guess you knew this already!

Comment: No problem @bill. That's how I understood it. And my wording wasn't that clear anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If the sum is not complicated, then why not use a more direct brute force approach?

```
{Sum[2 x, {x, 0, 3}], Table[2 x, {x, 0, 3}]}
```

or

```
#[2 x, {x, 0, 3}] & /@ {Sum, Table}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jim. But, as stated in the question, _"I don't want to change the definition of the summation `s`."_ Actually, this was a self-assigned exercise to learn about the Wolfram Language rewriting capabilities. I posted the question late in the evening, and I only realized this morning my intents were not clear. I rewrote the question to make that explicit. Sorry for having wasted your time.

Comment: Time wasn't wasted especially as the other answers show how many different ways *Mathematica* can solve a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html)and [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html).

```
ClearAll[sumTerms]
SetAttributes[sumTerms, HoldFirst]
sumTerms[sumSym_Symbol] :=
 Module[{ov = First@OwnValues[sumSym]},
  Values[ov /. Sum[f_, p__] :> Reap[Sum[Sow[f], p]]]
  ]
```

Then with

```
s := Sum[2 x, {x, 0, 3}]

sumTerms[s]
```

> ```
> {12, {{0, 2, 4, 6}}}
> ```

or

```
p := Sum[2 x + y, {x, 0, 3}, {y, -10, -8}]

sumTerms[p]
```

> ```
> {-72, {{-10, -9, -8, -8, -7, -6, -6, -5, -4, -4, -3, -2}}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Edmund. I have a hard time understanding `Values[ov /. Sum[f_, p__] :> Reap[Sum[Sow[f], p]]]` I understand it's a rewriting rule but the pattern is puzzling me. Could you elaborate a little on that?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I recommend the [Patterns overview](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsOverview.html) in the docs. The bits used above are shorthand `ReplaceAll`, `Blank` and friends, and `RuleDelayed`.

Comment: Actually, I missed the second use case for the [`Values`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values.html) function: _"
`Values[{key1val1,key2val2,…}]`
: gives a list of the vali in a list of rules.
"_ Things are clear now!

Answer (score 2):

I would go this way.

```
{Total[2 #], 2 #}&@Range[0, 3]
```

> {12, {0, 2, 4, 6}}

Comment: Thanks, Okkes. But, as stated in the question, _"I don't want to change the definition of the summation `s`."_ Actually, this was a self-assigned exercise to learn about the Wolfram Language rewriting capabilities. I posted the question late in the evening, and I only realized this morning my intents were not clear. I rewrote the question to make that explicit. Sorry for having wasted your time.

Comment: +1 To avoid doing the multiplications twice: `{Total[#], #} &[2 Range[0, 3]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
Reap[ReleaseHold[#1]]& @@ 
    ( OwnValues[s] /. (_ :>Sum[a_,b_]) -> Hold[Sum[Sow[a],b]])
```

> ```
> {12,{{0,2,4,6}}}
> ```

The idea is the rewrite the [`OwnValues`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OwnValues.html) associated with the symbol `s` to *inject* the [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html?q=Sow) function around the expression in the sum. Finally, the modified sum is evaluated inside a [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html?q=Reap) function to collect both the result and the individual terms "raised" by the Sow function.

I won't claim this is an optimal solution. It is merely the result of many trials and errors, especially because I had a hard time dealing with [`Hold`'ed](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold.html?q=Hold) expressions.