# Partial evaluation of a function

Tags: evaluation, term-rewriting, self-study

In the spirit of a [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211066/obtaining-the-terms-of-a-summation-alongside-the-result), this is a self-assigned exercise in order to understand how we can [control expression evaluation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EvaluationControl.html) with Mathematica.

So, given the following function definition:

```
f[x_] := Sin[Pi x] + Cos[Pi x]
```

By default, Mathematica will evaluate expressions as far as possible. So:

```
f[3]
```

> ```
> -1
> ```

However, and *without* having tho change the definition of `f`, I would like to obtain only a *partial evalutation* of the expression where the `x` argument is substituted, but where the `Cos` and `Sin` function aren't evaluated. In clear, I want that:

> ```
> Cos[3 π] + Sin[3 π]
> ```

After some trials and errors, I came to a `Block`-based solution given as [an answer below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211116/68791). But do you have other suggestions to achieve that result?

This question is really to *learn* how to control evaluation with Mathematica. I would prefer solutions that demonstrate how to apply the [functions given in the docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/EvaluationControl.html) on that particular case, rather than a more powerful and generic solution like [Mr. Wizard's `step` function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1447/68791).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I evaluate only one step of an expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/334/how-do-i-evaluate-only-one-step-of-an-expression) - In particular, `step[f[3]]` returns `Sin[π 3]+Cos[π 3]` (using `step` from @MrWizard's answer)

Comment: Thanks @Lukas, I indeed missed that answer in my list. From all the similar questions I saw, you make use of relatively complex functions to achieve the result I want. Is there something inherently wrong with the _one-liner_ I [suggested below](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/211116/68791)?

Comment: Nothing is inherently with with your approach. The big advantage of the `TraceScan` solution is that it will work for all functions, without you having to list everything that shouldn't be evaluated. But i guess it depends on what exactly you want to achieve (also, I wouldn't necessarily call it a "complex" function - it's essentially only two lines)

Comment: You're right @Lukas, Mr Wizard's `step` function isn't that long. But for a newcomer, it is not obvious to understand. I tried to apply `TraceScan` in my particular case. I tried variations along the lines of `TraceScan[HoldForm, f[3]]`. But it returns the fully evaluated function eaach time. Whereas `TraceScan[Print, f[3]]` display the individual evaluation steps. Obviously, I missed something important here :/

Comment: Additionally, since this is for my Wolfram Language learning efforts if you have a solution to avoid repeating `HoldForm` in `{Sin = HoldForm[Sin], Cos = HoldForm[Cos]}`--don't hesitate to mention it! A simple mapping does not work `Block[HoldForm /@ {Sin, Cos}, f[3]]`

Comment: Do you really want to control the order of evaluation, or do you just want to view the order of evaluation?

Comment: Well, @Carl, I'm not quite sure. This is really in the goal of understanding the evaluation process. Any solution showing how I can either limit the evaluation depth or stop the evaluation at a given subexpression would help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a whitelist of symbols, here's a flexible way to do it with `Inactivate` and some code-injection trickery:

```
$inactiveSyms = 
  Hold[{Sin, Cos, Tan}];(* in case you want to localize a symbol with OwnValues *)
withInactiveSymbols~SetAttributes~HoldAll
withInactiveSymbols[expr_, symList : Hold[{___Symbol}] | Automatic : Automatic] :=
 Replace[
  Thread[
   Replace[
    Thread[Replace[symList, Automatic :> $inactiveSyms]], 
    Hold[s_] :> Hold[s = Inactive[s]],
    1
    ],
   Hold
   ], 
  Hold[assigns_] :> Block[assigns, expr]
  ]
```

And it replaces the syms with their `Inactive` forms:

```
withInactiveSymbols[f[3]]

Inactive[Cos][3 \[Pi]] + Inactive[Sin][3 \[Pi]]
```

Note that you can easily change what to `Inactive`-ify on the fly:

```
withInactiveSymbols[f[3], Hold[{Sin, Tan}]]

-1 + Inactive[Sin][3 \[Pi]]
```

Here's a different layer of trickery:

```
partialEval[f_, var_ -> val_] :=
 With[
  {
   d = DownValues[f], 
   tag = Unique[partialEvalTag],
   v =
    ToExpression[
     Context[var] <> Block[{Internal`$ContextMarks = False}, ToString[var]]
     ]
   },
  SetAttributes[partialEvalTag, Temporary];
  Pick[
    Thread@Extract[d, {All, 2}, HoldForm],
    Map[
     Not@FreeQ[#, partialEvalTag] &,
      Keys[d] /. v -> partialEvalTag
     ]
    ] /. v -> val
  ]
```

This requires the variable *name* to be the same as expected, and so you can have `f[x_]` partially evaluate but `f[y_, z_]` not. Not sure if it's useful, but it is fun at a minimum.

```
f[x_] := Sin[Pi x] + Cos[Pi x]
f[y_, z_] := y + 1

partialEval[f, x -> 3]

{HoldForm[Sin[\[Pi] 3]+Cos[\[Pi] 3]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my initial solution:

```
Block[{Sin = HoldForm[Sin], Cos = HoldForm[Cos]}, f[3]]
```

> ```
> Cos[3 \[Pi]]+Sin[3 \[Pi]]
> ```

The idea is to use the [`Block`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html?q=Block) function to evaluate `f[3]` in an environment where the `Sin` and `Cos` symbols are temporarily rebound to their ["unevaluable" equivalent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldForm.html)<sup>1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup>I'm not sure this is the correct wording. Please correct me if necessary!</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution based on the [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html?q=Trace) function:

```
Trace[f[3]][[2]]
```

> ```
> Sin[\[Pi] 3]+Cos[\[Pi] 3]
> ```

Or better maybe:

```
 Trace[f[3], _[_] +_[_]]
```

> ```
> {Sin[\[Pi] 3]+Cos[\[Pi] 3]}
> ```